# Dictionary becomes list, not sure why

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following response which I get from an API. When I check the type of it I get dict but when I slice it for just the results, which also has key > value pairs, it becomes a list and I am not sure why.

```
responsefromapi = requests.get(url)
response = json.loads(responsefromapi.text)
print(type(response))
results = response["results"]
print(type(results))
```

Comment: When you "slice" it you are returning the type of that value specifically. It's a way to access the dictionary item via its key.

Comment: There are no slices here. Dictionary objects don't support slicing. What exactly do you mean? In May case, it looks like you are comparing two different things, why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: The json response you get has a property called `results` of type list. This has not changed the json itself

Answer (score 0):

The external is still a dictionary, but each value has its own type as well. In the below case it's a list.

```
>>> example_dict = {'key':['value']}  # make a dictionary
>>> type(example_dict)
<class 'dict'>
>>> type(example_dict['key'])  # access element via its key
<class 'list'>
```